# How to parse app link parameters to fallback url?

Tags: facebook, deep-linking, branch.io, applinks

I need to send custom firebase password-reset link, that should lead to app if it exists, or to firebase reset-password-page.

URL: myapp://page1?code=1234

I want next behavior:
If user has app, he redirect to app to page1.
If user not has app, i want to parse url parameters and go to fallback url - https://mywebsite.com/index?code=1234

Is it possible, using Branch.io or Facebook Deeplinks?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by integrating Branch SDK into your app. Except for handling the deeplink routing logic you need not handle any of the use cases that you have mentioned, Branch does all that for you. Follow the docs below for step by step info on integrating Branch SDK:

iOS: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/
android: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/

Comment: I need to send custom firebase password-reset link, that should lead to app if it exists, or to firebase reset-password-page.